# Microsoft Azure run function after x minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm hosting my C# ASP.net website on azure currently, and i'm searching for a function that let's me execute code to change database entry's after x minutes after the request.

So i example:

User visits my website http://www.test.com/ 
Users leaves my site.
5 minutes later i change a variable in my database.

I already found something called [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs), but it's not the perfect fit.

Comment: Why are you changing a variable in your database in this way? The reason I ask is that you may be going about this backwards ...

Comment: Perhaps logging the last time an action was performed by the user would be better, that way you don't need to run a process afterwards

Comment: My website creates a temp e-mail account for the visitor. That email needs to be deleted after x minutes. @twoleggedhorse

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, you could log the action into [Azure Storage Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues) and specify the interval of time from now during which the message will be invisible as follows:

```
queue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage("hello world"), initialVisibilityDelay:TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

Then, you could work with WebJobs SDK to trigger your Azure queue storage. More details, you could refer to [How to use Azure queue storage with the WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues). Also, you could leverage Azure Functions Queue bindings to achieve the similar requirement, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue).

Moreover, you could also leverage the [Scheduled messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages) from Azure Service Bus. Also, here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383362/what-happens-when-you-try-to-cancel-a-scheduled-azure-service-bus-message-that-h/45409586#45409586), you could refer to the related code for sending a scheduled message. For processing the messages, you could refer to [How to use Azure Service Bus with the WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus) or [Azure Functions Service Bus bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus).

> My website creates a temp e-mail account for the visitor. That email needs to be deleted after x minutes.

Per my understanding,  when you creating the temp e-mail account, you could record the create time and the expire time, and valid the temp account is valid or not when accessing your website. Then you could create a Recurring job (e.g. azure webjobs ([TimerTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions)), or [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/),etc) to retrieve the expired accounts and delete them.

Comment: So your answer is basicly: Create a message pool, and read that message pool every x minutes?

Comment: My idea is that we could push the message to the pool and make the message visible after x minutes. The `QueueTrigger` for WebJobs and Service Bus trigger binding for Azure Functions would continuously monitor the pool, and automatically retrieve your message if it is visible. Please have a look at the tutorials in my answer.