# Can I run a Azure function once on a specific date triggered by my asp.net mvc site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-functions

I know I can create a scheduled Azure function to run on a schedule. But what I want is to be able to run a Azure function once given a specific date/time I pass it, along with some data parameters.

Ex. I'm scheduling classes in my site and I want to email out all students when the class is over. So when the class is created for Monday October 9th @ 4:00PM I want to send a message to trigger my Azure function on that same day, but like 1 hour later at 5:00PM. And I want to pass it some info like the class id or something. I also want to be able to remove this queued trigger if the class is canceled.

Is this possible in Azure and my ASP.Net MVC site?

Answer (score 3):

Another potential way to achieve this would be using [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview). I adopted this solution off of Pattern #5, since you have potential human interaction in the form of a class cancellation.

The below is an untested rough framework of what your orchestrator function would look like. Your email logic would go in a function called SendEmail that utilizes an ActivityTrigger, and you could add new classes and cancel them by utilizing [these APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-http-api).

```
public static async Task Run(DurableOrchestrationContext ctx)
{
    var classInfo = ctx.GetInput<ClassInfo>();
    var targetDateTime = DateTime.Parse(classInfo.ClassEndDateString);
    var maxTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(96, 0, 0);
    using (var timeoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        while(true)
        {
            TimeSpan timeLeft = targetDateTime.Subtract(ctx.CurrentUtcDateTime);
            if(timeLeft <= TimeSpan.Zero) {
                break;
            }

            DateTime checkTime; 
            if(timeLeft > maxTimeSpan) {
                checkTime = ctx.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(maxTimeSpan);
            } else {
                checkTime = ctx.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(timeLeft);
            }

            Task durableTimeout = ctx.CreateTimer(checkTime, timeoutCts.Token);

            Task<bool> cancellationEvent = ctx.WaitForExternalEvent<bool>("Cancellation");
            if (cancellationEvent == await Task.WhenAny(cancellationEvent, durableTimeout))
            {
                timeoutCts.Cancel();
                return
            }
        }
        await ctx.CallActivityAsync("SendEmail", classInfo.ClassData);
    }
}

public class ClassInfo {
    public string ClassEndDateString {get; set; }
    public string ClassData {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> My classes might be scheduled upto 30 days ahead of the current date.

Per my understanding, you could also leverage the [Scheduled messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages) from Azure Service Bus and set the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property for your message. For more details about triggering the service bus queue message, you could follow [Azure Functions Service Bus bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus). For sending the message, you could install the [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) in your MVC application and leverage [QueueClient.ScheduleMessageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient.schedulemessageasync?view=azure-dotnet) for sending scheduled message and [QueueClient.CancelScheduledMessageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.cancelscheduledmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet) for cancelling the scheduled message. Moreover, you could follow the code snippet in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383362/what-happens-when-you-try-to-cancel-a-scheduled-azure-service-bus-message-that-h/45409586#45409586).

Comment: Hi Bruce, would these scheduled messages be able to run a Azure function? I'm a little lost reading through the service bus bindings link you included. What exactly is the service bus bindings used for??

Comment: You could use the `ServiceBusTrigger` with your azure function for triggering the scheduled queue message from the specific service bus queue, then extract the message info and send the email to your students. Here is a trigger example, you could refer to [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---attributes).

Comment: do you know if Azure has a phone number I can call and ask questions, even if I have to pay. I just feel a little lost and reading through all the docs just takes too long

Comment: I would recommend you get started with azure function triggered by azure service bus queue by yourself. You could follow [tutorial1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function) and [tutorial2](https://serversncode.com/azure-functions-service-bus-queue-trigger/) to create your azure function on azure portal. In addition, you could follow [How to create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: Moreover, you could develop azure function on your local side via visual studio. Details you could follow [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/) and this video [Function Junction Ep5: Service Bus Triggers](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-Azure/Function-Junction-Ep5-Service-Bus-Triggers).

Comment: yes, I Bruce, I'm familiar with Azure functions but I'm a little lost on the go between my asp.net mvc site and triggering the functions on a specific date using the service bus queue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [queue trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#handling-poison-queue-messages) for this. You can have your MVC app add [CloudQueueMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueuemessage?view=azure-dotnet) objects to an Azure Storage Queue. These messages can contain the data parameters (i.e. student list, professor name, etc.) that are unique to the class, and you can delay the visibility in the Queue with the `visibilitytimeout` parameter when you perform the ["Put Message"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Put-Message?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

You can calculate the `visibilitytimeout` by subtracting the desired time from the current time. Note that the timeout cannot be longer than 7 days, so if these events are being queued for long periods of times, you may be forced to reinsert the message into the queue repeatedly until you get within the 7 day range and you can successfully process the message.

Comment: hi Connor. So if I want to trigger my function at say MOnday @4PM, would I set the 'NextVisibleTime' to Monday @ 4PM. Then when it becomes visible it triggers the function to run? Is that how it works?

Comment: It turns out that `NextVisibleTime` is a readonly field. I edited the answer to reflect how you would actually go about adding a message with your desired `NextVisibleTime`.

Comment: I don't think this will be a good solution for me, or maybe too complex to have to keep re insterting the message into the queue every 7 days. My classes might be scheduled upto 30 days ahead of the current date